# Html2canvas does not print div with ng-show that has condition hiding

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf, html2canvas

my code is this:

```js
case "ExcelDataRepresentation":
  try {
    const imgData = await html2canvas(element, {
      scale: 2.0,
      width: $(window).width(),
      height: $(window).height()
    });

    const pdfWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();

    // Calculate the aspect ratio to maintain the image proportions
    const aspectRatio = imgData.width / imgData.height;
    const pdfHeight = pdfWidth / aspectRatio;

    // Check if there is enough space on the current page to add the image
    if (currentY + pdfHeight > doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight()) {
      // If not enough space, start a new page or handle it as needed
      doc.addPage();
      currentY = 0; // Reset the currentY position for the new page
    }

    // Add the image to the current page
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, currentY, pdfWidth, pdfHeight, null, 'FAST');

    // Update the current position on the page
    currentY += pdfHeight + 5; // You can adjust the distance between images or lines
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred while adding image to PDF:", error);
  }
  break;
```

I am trying to print divs that have the data-printpdf data-type="ExcelDataRepresentation", however html2canvas when it finds divs with ng show that hides the elements if a certain condition is met i.e. if it finds divs that are generated by radio buttons that contain yes and no, if you click on it generates this div that contains form structures dynamically, so it is not present in the html code, is the only way to hook them is to take the parent class,what I expect is that html2canvas will track down these hidden divs with ng-show and print them to me.